# Wordpress styles in editor only works with "watch"

Tags: php, wordpress, webpack

I am using **Wordpress 5.4** with the **Gutenberg editor** and **Webpack 4.2** to build assets. I want my  styles (`app.css`) to be loaded when editing a page or post.

In **functions.php**, I added:

```
function add_theme_style_to_editor(){
    add_theme_support( 'editor-styles' );
    add_editor_style( 'public/build/app.css' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_theme_style_to_editor' );
```

Whenever I run `yarn watch` everything works as expected, my styles are loaded in the editor. However, if i run `yarn build` to generate minified build files, it does not work! Even though the  minified file is generated succesfully in the same place with the same name, it does not matter. **What could be going wrong?**

**Edit:** when I remove from my file `app.scss` the line `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`, and I remove all bootstrap-related styles, the other styles do work when building files. I still don't understand though why everything does work fine when running `yarn watch`.

**Edit2:** if I use the following in **functions.php** it works, with bootstrap and all. Only now the whole backend is affected and not only the editor:

```
function add_theme_style(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'these-style', get_theme_file_uri( 'public/build/app.css' ), false );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'add_theme_style' );
```

What is going on?

In case it helps, here is **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "webpack -p"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.8.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1"
  }
}
```

And **webpack.config.js**:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: "./assets/app.js" // this also contains an scss-import that will result in app.css, apart from app.js
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/build"),
        filename: "[name].js",
        publicPath: "public/build"
    },
    watch: true,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {presets: ["es2015"]}
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        })
    ]
}
```

Comment: If you use vscode I recommend this plugin [versionlens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pflannery.vscode-versionlens). You have old devDependencies e.g. `babel-core` should be `@babel/core etc`. Does yarn build show any errors in the console? Does the app.css file appear in `public/build/`, or if you open the page is there an error in the console?

Answer (score 0):

I think the function should look something like this. The [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_editor_style/) says that the style is in the root template folder, so you should use `get_template_directory_uri`

```
function add_theme_style_to_editor() {
  add_theme_support('editor-styles');
  add_editor_style(get_template_directory_uri() . 'public/build/app.css');
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'add_theme_style_to_editor');
```

Here is my Wordpress example, see [devDependencies](https://github.com/tomik23/docker-wordpress-xdebug/blob/master/package.json#L21)